# keeping tabs fixed on all screen of android development

Tags: android

I am new on android i am making  an app having few tabs using fragment. Is there any way to keep tabs fixed on all screens or will I have to copy the code for tabs in all activities?

Comment: what do you mean by 'fixed' ?

Comment: this may help you https://github.com/rameshkec85/BottomTabsFragmentTabHost

Comment: Check here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTabHost.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple way to do this is

- Take linear layout at top & take relative layout for rest of the screen
- Add number of tabs/buttons/imagebuttons you want
- Apply listener for each button according to that button you can change the things which are in relative layout.

I think, this will be the simple & efficient way to handle the things.